# Where can I find documentation to support this behavior?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking over some previous developers code and I come across this line:

```
location.href = '#' + variable;
```

Which has the effect of updating `location.hash`. Remove the '#' and of course it redirects to the non-existent url. Playing around a bit it seems I can set the hash via `location.href` as long as the value starts with '#'. This line or similar is used a lot, but I can't seem to find any documentation the supports this behavior of it updating `location.hash` by setting `location.href` this way.

I would like to see something showing this isn't just a happy accident that this works so I don't have to re-code all the situations where this is used. Anything you can link me to would help.

Would it be better to just changes these to properly set the `location.hash` anyway?

Thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess this is because setting location.href to *value* is supposed to have the same behaviour as clicking a link whose href=*value* would; it's not supposed to replace the contents of the address bar, because then you'd have to build absolute URLs everytime you wanted to use `location.href`.

Assigning values to `location` and `location.href` was apparently there back in Javascript 1.0, so it's entirely possible this wasn't properly specified anywhere – neither the Mozilla or Microsoft documentation go into detail. HTML5 [specifies the behaviour](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-location-href), most likely retroactively.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to start your journey on the location properties.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location

By the way, `#something` is a valid url and assigning a new url to window.location cause the browser to navigate to the new destination.

`#something` is called hash and direct the browser to an anchor on the current document, or to the top of the document if the anchor does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/DHTML_javascript/0596004672_jvdhtmlckbk-chp-10-sect-2.html

So what happens is when you set location.href to something that is not seen as an absolute path. The browser will automatically put the current url prepended to whatever value you are trying to set it to.

So "#section1" = "www.mysitethatistoocoolforschool.com#section1"

and "section1" = "www.mysitethatistoocoolforschool.comsection1" (this does not exist)

Answer (score 0):

This URLs with a `'#'` char are called anchor based URLs, they're not supposed to redirect the user from the page, instead they just update the position of the page by some offset, the same way as setting the `location.hash` you cited.

As stated by Sii this works because when you change the `location.href` value it's like you're clicking on a link for example then you have the following equivalence:

```
<a href="#toc" >Go to Table of Contents</a>
```

Is the same as:

```
location.href = "#toc";
```

Both of them would result in your `location.hash` variable to have the value `toc`.